# How do I pass a Mongoose Collection to a function in a js file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, ejs

I am working on a project where I want to be able to search a database of motorcycles based on a form input similar to what you would find on Revzilla.com after selecting My Garage at the top. This form will be used in multiple locations in the project.

I pass bikeLists to the index from my routes/index file

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const bikeDBModel = require('../models/bike')
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { collection } = require('../models/bike');

const BikesDBConnection = mongoose.connection.useDb('bikes')


router.get('/',(req,res)=>{;
    const collection = BikesDBConnection.collection('harley-davidson')//Harley is the only Maker supported at the moment(change to all-bikes) soon.
    res.render('index', {'bikesList':collection})
});

module.exports = router;
```

and I can get it to show up on my view/index.ejs file

```
<%= bikesList %> 

<%- include('./partials/part-bikeSelector.ejs') %>
```

**UPDATE: **From my research, I found that you *should* be able to get it to work by doing the following, but I still get the "bikesList not defined" error

```
<%- include('./partials/part-bikeSelector.ejs', {bikesList:bikeList) %>
```

but can't get it to the included file under part-bikeSelector.ejs

```
<%= bikesList %> 

<form action="" method="post" class="bikeSelectorForm">
    <div class="yearSelect">
        <select name="bikeYear" id="bikeYear" onchange="getBikeModels()">
            <option disabled selected value>Year</option>
            <% for( let i = new Date().getFullYear(); i >= 2000; i-- ) { %>
                <option value="<%= i %>"><%= i %></option>
            <% } %>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="makeSelect">
        <select name="bikeMake" id="bikeMake">
            <option disabled selected value>Motorcycle Make</option>
            <option value="Harley">Harley Davidson</option>
            <optgroup label="Coming Soon">
                <option disabled value="Yamaha">Yamaha</option>
                <option disabled value="Honda">Honda</option>
                <option disabled value="Kawasaki">Kawasaki</option>
                <option disabled value="Indian">Indian</option>
            </optgroup>
        </select>
    </div>
</form>

<script src="/js/bikeSelector.js"></script>
```

and ideally I'd like to pass it one further to a pure js file that's linked from the part-bikeSelector.ejs

```
const bikeYear_formField = document.getElementById('bikeYear');

//get list of models based on year and make of form fields
function getBikeModels() {
    console.log(bikesList);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was looking at this all wrong. The answer was to rethink my approach. I created a REST API that I can fetch all the data when I need it.